# Is there away to handle scroll area well which will solve my issue here?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have been checking on having this scroll area to be functional but in vain.
What can I add or remove to make it work?

What I am trying to achieve is to have the labels and the text browsers scrollable because I have many of them to be added and the user should be able to see all of them

Code for this is as shown below

```
    self.rylgh_grb = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.flow_para_grb)
    self.rylgh_grb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1120, 20, 200, 321))
    
    
  some buttons and textbrowsers goes here
    
   
    self.layoutWidget_7.setObjectName("layoutWidget_7")
    self.horizontalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_7)
    self.horizontalLayout_7.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.horizontalLayout_7.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_7")
    self.label_38 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_7)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setBold(False)
    font.setWeight(50)
    self.label_38.setFont(font)
    self.label_38.setObjectName("label_38")
    self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.label_38)
    self.r_clr_pshbt = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget_7)
    self.r_clr_pshbt.setObjectName("r_clr_pshbt")
    self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.r_clr_pshbt)

    self.r_calculate_pshbt = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget_7)
    self.r_calculate_pshbt.setObjectName("r_calculate_pshbt")
    self.r_calculate_pshbt.setText("Calculate")
    self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.r_calculate_pshbt)

    self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.flow_para_grb)

    self.scrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 211, 301))
    self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
    self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
    self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
    self.scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    
    self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 209, 299))
    self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")

    self.i_flo_grb = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
    self.i_flo_grb.setGeometry(QtCore.t(10, 10, 201, 371))
```

How it appears

[image]

Comment: The code in the question doesn't reflect what is shown in the image. Please provide a [mre]. Also read the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: What is the problem ? That the text fields are cut on the right side ?